# My overloaded generic method is not called

Tags: c#, generics, overloading

I write this piece of code in one of my C# project:

```
public static class GetAppendReceiver
{
    public static AppendReceiver<DataType> Get<DataType>(AppendReceiver<DataType>.DataProcessor processor0, int delayIn = 0)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }

    public static AppendReceiver<string> Get(AppendReceiver<string>.DataProcessor processor0, int delayIn = 0)
    {
        return new StringAppendReceiver(processor0, delayIn);
    }
}

public abstract class AppendReceiver<DataType>
{
    public delegate void DataProcessor(DataType data);
    ...
}
```

`AppendReceiver<DataType>` is an Abstract class, `DataProcessor` is a delegate type.

When calling `GetAppendReceiver.Get` with a string `DataProcessor` I expect the overloaded function to be called, but I get the `InvalidOperationException`.

Here is my call:

```
class ClassA<DataType>
{
    public void RegisterAppendReceiver(AppendReceiver<DataType>.DataProcessor receiver)
    {
        appendReceivers.Add(GetAppendReceiver.Get(receiver, Delay));
    }
}
```

Example of `RegisterAppendReceiver` call:

```
myObject.RegisterAppendReceiver(myMethod);
```

Where `myMethod` is defined like this:

```
public void writeMessage(string strMessageIn)
```

My question is why I get the wrong overload called, and how can I force the language to call the overload I want ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eric Lippert answers this question concisely in his article [Generics are not Templates](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/07/30/generics-are-not-templates.aspx)

I don't want to copy the entire article.  So the relevant point is this:

> We do the overload resolution once and bake in the result.

So the C# compiler decides, at the time it compiles RegisterAppendReceiver, which overload of "GetAppendReceiver.Get" it is going to call.  Since, at that point, the only thing it knows about DataType is that DataType can be anything at all, it compiles in the call to the overload that takes an AppendReceiver.DataProcessor, not an AppendReceiver.DataProcessor.

By comparison, the C++ compiler does not behave this way.  Each and every time a generic call is made, the compiler does the substitution over again.  This is one reason C++ compilers are much slower than C# compilers.

Comment: Ok, I understand the difference, thanks for the clarification. Is there a way I can achieve my goal with C# ?

Comment: Per Eric's article, dynamic will do it, but it will resolve the type at runtime not compile time.  So long as performance isn't a problem, that will work.

Comment: @AMDG You can also simply use inheritance in this case. This seems to me like the classical example of an *abstract factory* pattern -- the GoF describes perfectly how to do this using standard inheritance.

Comment: @atlaste what is GoF ?

Comment: "Gang Of Four" -- it's commonly used as abbreviation for the 'standard' book on design patterns: https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Design_Patterns (the one on the right)

Comment: The more recent Lippert series, Wizards and Warriors, seems pertitnent http://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/